# How can I create a OpenEBS cstor pool?

Tags: storage, openebs

Setup -- OpenEBS 0.7
K8S -- 1.10, GKE

I am having 3 node cluster with 2 disks each per node. Can I use these disks for cstor pool creation? How can I do that? Should I have to manually select the disks?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use the disks attached to the Nodes for creating cStor Storage Pool using OpenEBS.The main prereuisties is to unmount the disks if it is being used.

With the latest OpenEBS 7.0 release, the following disk types/paths are excluded by OpenEBS data plane components Node Disk Manager(NDM) which identifies the disks to create cStor pools on nodes.

```
loop,/dev/fd0,/dev/sr0,/dev/ram,/dev/dm-
```

You can also customize by adding more disk types associated with your nodes. For example, used disks, unwanted disks and so on. This must be done in the 'openebs-operator-0.7.0.yaml' file that you downloaded before installation. Add the device path in openebs-ndm-config under ConfigMap in the openebs-operator.yaml file as follows.

```
"exclude":"loop,/dev/fd0,/dev/sr0,/dev/ram,/dev/dm-"
Example:

 {
          "key": "path-filter",
          "name": "path filter",
          "state": "true",
          "include":"",
          "exclude":"loop,/dev/fd0,/dev/sr0,/dev/ram,/dev/dm-"
}
```

So just install openebs-oprator.yaml which is mentioned in the  **docs.openebs.io** and after the installation it will detect the disks. Follow the instruction given in the doc. You can create pool either by manually selecting the disks or by auto way.